# Can not edit automatically created "G Suite Marketplace Integration Client" OAuth 2.0 client IDs

Tags: google-api, google-console-developer

I created a project in google console.
Filled out the OAuth consent screen form. Set application type as internal.
Enabled "Google Drive API" and filled out the Drive UI Integration form.
Enabled "G Suite Marketplace SDK" and filled out the Configuration form.
After saving the Configuration form for "G Suite Marketplace SDK", I go to the credentials for "G Suite Marketplace SDK" and choose automatically created "G Suite Marketplace Integration Client" OAuth 2.0 client IDs.
I would like add an Authorized redirect URIs.
When I click save, I've got an error message "You do not have permission to perform this action. Tracking Number: xxxxxxx".
I've got the same error if I did not any changes, just click save.
In case account permission, I use super Admin account.

I tried to do the same using different account from different GSuite subscription, but got the same result.

Could anyone tell if this issue common or is there any workaround to save redirect url, because it prevents me from running integration with external apps that I need. Thanks in advance.

[image: Error message]

Comment: were you able to get around the issue? I believe it may be due to your app being in the verfication process.